# Problem with Numerical Solution for motion of a particle around Black Hole using Fourth order Runge Kutta method

Tags: black-holes, computational-physics, differential-equations

I have been trying to plot the variation of radial distance of a particle orbiting a Black Hole. The variation of radial distance from Black Hole is given by second order differential equation,
$$
\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\frac{GM}{r^2} + \frac{l^2}{r^3} - \frac{3GMl^2}{r^4}
$$

For solving the differential equation, I have used fourth order runge kutta method.This is the [python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334558/runge-kutta-4th-order-method-to-solve-second-order-odes).
When the solution is plotted, the  radial distance is increasing linearly with time. That doesn't seem right.I tried various initial conditions, but the solution plot is either linearly increasing or decreasing. So, how can i solve the given differential equation numerically, and what is the reason for this error ?.

Below is the program i executed.

```
from math import pi
from numpy import arange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

# y' = u
# u' = -y

#second order ode,F(r,v,t) GM=1.334e20, l**2 = 4.46e15 
def F(y, u, x):     
    return -(1.334e20/y**2) + (4.46e15/y**3) - 3*(1.334e20)*(4.46e15)/y**4

a = 0
b = 3000  #time from 0 to 3000
N =100
h = (b-a)/N

xpoints = arange(a,b,h)
ypoints = []
upoints = []

y = 1.5e11  #initial radial distance
u = 29.76e3 #initial velocity

for x in xpoints:
    ypoints.append(y)
    upoints.append(u)

    m1 = h*u
    k1 = h*F(y, u, x)  #(x, v, t)

    m2 = h*(u + 0.5*k1)
    k2 = h*F(y+0.5*m1, u+0.5*k1, x+0.5*h)

    m3 = h*(u + 0.5*k2)
    k3 = h*F(y+0.5*m2, u+0.5*k2, x+0.5*h)

    m4 = h*(u + k3)
    k4 = h*F(y+m3, u+k3, x+h)

    y += (m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4)/6
    u += (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6

plot(xpoints, ypoints)
show()
```

Comment: Have you tried running it for a longer time?

Comment: Yes. The parameters i have given here is that of the earth. For example when i give time upto 3.156x10^7 seconds, the radius goes almost constant upto 2.8x10^7 seconds and then suddenly falls to -6.5x10^12 .

Comment: I got the same result, your $\ddot r$ is constant 0.0059?

Comment: What steps have you under taken to check your code? For example have you plotted your function $F$ to see if it makes sense?

Comment: I got this differential equation from Thomas A. Moore textbook. I plotted radial acceleration against radial distance taking r from range 1 to 10. As r increases,radial acceleration goes from -1.75 and flattens to 0. Which means there is no radial acceleration as radial distance is high. So, It does makes sense.